# Kerasで畳み込みネットワークの学習　精度の上がり方について

Tags: python, 機械学習, 画像, keras

私は畳み込みネットワークを用いて画像の識別をしています．
実際にプログラムを動かしていくと，下の画像のように動作の開始直後はなかなか精度が上がらず，途中から急に精度が上昇し始めました．どういった原因が考えられるでしょうか．
回答よろしくお願いします．
[image: 左が精度グラフ，右が損失関数グラフ]

Comment: 学習率の設定がよくないとか？設定変えたらどうなりますかね？

Comment: Adadeltaを使っているのですが，学習率をデフォルトの1から0.001に変えたところ，収束が速くなったように感じました．いくつか試して最適解を試そうと思います．
それとふと気になったのですが，optimizerはどれがいい，優秀だとかはあるのでしょうか？
軽く調べてみましたがピンときませんでした．

Comment: 用途によって優秀かどうかは変わるかもしれませんが、今のところ一番安定しているといわれているのはAdamではないでしょうか？AdadeltaやRMSpropの改良版と言われています。Adamの改良版でEveというのもあるらしいですが、新しすぎて論文を読まないとどんなアルゴリズムかわかりません。。